# Passing axios fetched prop from Parent to Child returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I know this question has been asked already, but the various [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66439715/typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-x-of-undefined-when-passing-data-from-paren) provided just don't seem to work in my case.

Parent component

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Child from "../../components/fragments/Child";

// Fetches data with no errors
export default function Parent() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      await axios.get("http://localhost:xxxxx").then((res) => {
        setPost(res.data);
      });
    };
    fetchPost();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Child post={post} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Child Component

```
export default function Child({ post }) {
    return (
        <>
        {console.log(post)}
        {/* Sometimes returns an error because axios hasn't finished fetching */}
        </>
    );
  }
```

The `Parent` fetches the data from server with no errors. However, when I pass the data to the `Child` it sometimes throws `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"`. That breaks the whole application since the `Child` is trying to access `post` prop which is still in its initial empty array state before the data is fetched with `axios`.

Something like `ComponentDidMount()` does not work because the component maybe has mounted but the data is still being fetched by `axios`.

What is the best way to get around this problem? How can I always have the `post` data in `Child` passed by the `Parent` and avoid the `"TypeError:..."` screen of failure when trying to access the prop?

Comment: `Child` is passed valid `post` prop on the initial render, an empty array (`[]`). Are you sure you are updating the `post` state in the parent to what you expect it to be? Seems you are at some point updating the `post` state to be undefined and then accessing it in the child. You can conditionally render the `Child` component if `post` is undefined for some reason, but this just masks the real issue in your code.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for steering me in the right direction by suggesting to conditionally render the Child component. I will try it out and see if the desired result can be achieved.

Comment: It solved my problem, thanks so much. If you write an answer with an example I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are at some point updating the `post` state to be undefined and then accessing it in the child. You can conditionally render the `Child` component if `post` is undefined/[falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) for some reason.

```
export default function Parent() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      await axios.get("http://localhost:xxxxx").then((res) => {
        setPost(res.data);
      });
    };
    fetchPost();
  }, []);

  return post ? <Child post={post} /> : null;
}
```

Or defensively render null in `Child` if `post` prop is undefined/falsey.

```
export default function Child({ post }) {
  return post ? (
    <>
      .... child post JSX
    </>
  ) : null;
}
```

Or provide an initial value if `post` is undefined. Note that this misses the edge case if `post` prop exists and is some other falsey value (`null`, `0`, `false`, etc), so beware.

```
export default function Child({ post = [] }) {
  return (
    <>
      .... child post JSX
    </>
  );
}
```